# IIS URL Rewrite {R:N} clarification

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting

I've not been able to understand the purpose of {R:N}. Could anyone please clarify when to use
`{R:0}` vs. `{R:1}`

usage example:

```xml
<action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" />
```

I've seen ScottGu using {R:1}

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/20/tip-trick-fix-common-seo-problems-using-the-url-rewrite-extension.aspx

Whereas, below has {R:0}

http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2009/11/27/iis-url-rewrite-rewriting-non-www-to-www.aspx

Had a look at the IIS link below but could not quite digest the definition below:

> Back-references to condition patterns are identified by {C:N} where N is from 0 to 9; back-references to rule pattern are identified by {R:N} where N is from 0 to 9. Note that for both types of back-references, {R:0} and {C:0}, will contain the matched string

Answer (score 119, accepted):

As per the documentation:

> When an ECMAScript pattern syntax is used, a back-reference can be
>   created by putting parenthesis around the part of the pattern that
>   must capture the back-reference.

So taking the example that follows in the documentation:

```
^(www\.)(.*)$
```

And using the input string `www.foo.com` in the **conditions**, you will have:

```
{C:0} - www.foo.com
{C:1} - www.
{C:2} - foo.com
```

To make it simple:

- `{R:x}` is used as back reference from the rule pattern (`<match url="...">`).
- `{C:x}` is used as back reference from the condition pattern (`<conditions><add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="..."></conditions>`)
- The `0` reference contains the whole input string
- The `1` reference will contain the first part of the string matching the pattern in the first parenthesis `()`, the `2` reference the second one, etc...up to the reference number `9`

Note:

> When "Wildcard" pattern syntax is used, the back-references are always
>   created when an asterisk symbol (*) is used in the pattern. No
>   back-references are created when "?" is used in the pattern.

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#Using_back-references_in_rewrite_rules

Comment: In case it helps someone, this also is a related and a very helpful link: https://nicolas.guelpa.me/blog/2015/02/21/rewrite-redirect-iis.html

Comment: @niki b: your blog did help me a lot because of what you say explicitly "_Important: The rule is only applied to the path; don’t let the name url fool you. (for example, in http://example.com/test, the scheme and domain name are ignored for the “url” matching)_", and "_Always remember when you debug a redirect (specifically a 301) that browsers tend to cache them and that it can lead to frustration when you change the rule but nothing happens…_".
Please correct you example with the domain name using the {R:X} because it is confusing, we don't have access to it with the Rules.

Comment: @DanielLobo I am glad the blog helped you. I did not write it though so if you want, you can contact the blogger directly.  But it's good you pointed it out here for people to be aware of that.