# IIS: URL Rewrite /signalr/ and /api/ to port 8080

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, signalr, self-hosting, arr

I have a self-hosted API running on port 8080. On port 80 is my web server (IIS 7.5) with a website I can't touch. I added an application "MyApiTestsite". Now all requests to /api/ or /signalr/ I would like to forward to port 8080:

```
http://mycompany/MyApiTestsite           -> untouched
http://mycompany/MyApiTestsite/signalr/* -> http://mycompany:8080/signalr/*
http://mycompany/MyApiTestsite/api/*     -> http://mycompany:8080/api/*
```

I already installed `ARR` (is this even necessary?) and `URL Rewrite`.

Here's my rule I have so far (for SignalR):

```
<rule name="Rewrite SignalR to port 8080" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="signalr/*" />
  <serverVariables>
    <set name="SERVER_PORT" value="8080" />
  </serverVariables>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" logRewrittenUrl="false" />
</rule>
```

I checked the log-files and the rule gets matched. However, it doesn't work at all:

- I don't know how to get rid of the RelativePath (my application) `MyApiTestsite`
- If I check logs the port didn't get replaced

Log:

```
RULE_EVALUATION_END RuleName="Rewrite SignalR to port 8080", RequestURL="MyApiTestsite/signalr/hubs", QueryString="", StopProcessing="true", Succeeded="true"

URL_REWRITE_END RequestURL="/MyApiTestsite/signalr/hubs"

GENERAL_CHILD_REQUEST_START SiteId="4", RequestURL="http://mycompany:80/MyApiTestsite/signalr/hubs", RequestVerb="GET", RecursiveLevel="1"
```

**Update:**
I now tried it according to [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosag/archive/2010/04/02/setting-up-a-reverse-proxy-using-iis-url-rewrite-and-arr.aspx) post. However, it still doesn't work. The URL seems good but the MvcHandler takes over and returns a 404:

> URL_REWRITE_END    RequestURL="http://mycompany:8080/signalr/hubs"
>
> USER_SET   AuthType="", UserName="", SupportsIsInRole="true"
>
> HANDLER_CHANGED
>   OldHandlerName="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0",
>   NewHandlerName="System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler",
>   NewHandlerModules="ManagedPipelineHandler",
>   NewHandlerScriptProcessor="",
>   NewHandlerType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler, System.Web.Mvc,
>   Version=5.1.0.0"
>
> GENERAL_SEND_CUSTOM_ERROR  HttpStatus="404", HttpSubStatus="4",
>   FileNameOrURL="404.htm"

**Update 2:**

Here's a picture of what I want to do...

[image]

**Update 3**
This time I tried using `Server Farms` instead. My URL got changed as it's supposed to be but then it got changed back to the old URL:

```
ARR_WEBFARM_ROUTED WebFarm="mycompany API", Algorithm="LeastRequests"
HANDLER_CHANGED OldHandlerName="", NewHandlerName="ApplicationRequestRoutingHandler", NewHandlerModules="ApplicationRequestRouting", NewHandlerScriptProcessor="", NewHandlerType=""
ARR_SERVER_ROUTED RoutingReason="LoadBalancing", Server="mycompany", State="Active", TotalRequests="1", FailedRequests="0", CurrentRequests="1", BytesSent="0", BytesReceived="0", ResponseTime="0"
GENERAL_SET_REQUEST_HEADER HeaderName="Max-Forwards", HeaderValue="10", Replace="true"
GENERAL_SET_REQUEST_HEADER HeaderName="X-Forwarded-For", HeaderValue="xxx.xx.xx.xxx:52327", Replace="true"
GENERAL_SET_REQUEST_HEADER HeaderName="X-ARR-SSL", HeaderValue="", Replace="true"
GENERAL_SET_REQUEST_HEADER HeaderName="X-ARR-ClientCert", HeaderValue="", Replace="true"
GENERAL_SET_REQUEST_HEADER HeaderName="X-ARR-LOG-ID", HeaderValue="f8exxxc2-7a6d-4cf6-a3c6-ecde245a0d80", Replace="true"
GENERAL_SET_REQUEST_HEADER HeaderName="Connection", HeaderValue="", Replace="true"
//>>>>>now it gets changed back!!! Why????<<<<<<
URL_CHANGED OldUrl="http://mycompany API/signalr/hubs", NewUrl="/MyApiTestsite/signalr/hubs"
```

Comment: Is your IIS configured correcyly? see http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/supported-platforms for exact spesificaitons

Comment: Let's put it this way: If I hardcode the API/SignalR access on port 8080 and use CORS then everything works as expected. However, I would like to hide this information from the user.

Comment: ARR should not be necessary, just URL Rewrite.

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  The (correctly) rewritten URL gets hijacked and reverted back to its original value.  It appears to be an incompatibility between URL Rewrite/ARR and MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Configure the following **URL Rewrite** rule:

```
Requested URL: Matches the pattern
Using: Regular Expressions
Pattern: MyApiTestsite/(signalr/.*)
Action: Rewrite
Rewrite URL: http://mycompany:8080/{R:1}
```

EDIT: `{R:1}` matches the 1st captured regexp group in this case what matches `(signalr/.*)`. If it was `{R:0}` instead, it would have put the whole relative URL that was matched.
See [IIS URL Rewrite {R:N} clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16998832/iis-url-rewrite-rn-clarification) for more info.

Comment: Thanks. However, I don't think my rule is wrong as it gets applied. Question is why does it get changed back...

Comment: Technically your rule is not wrong, but it does not do what you want - e.g. to remove the MyApiTestsite from the URL. The rule I suggested to you should do that.

Comment: Also my suggestion is related to use of simple URL Rewrite. I do not think you need Server Farms at all for the setup you are intending.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: This works!

```
<rewrite>
        <rewriteMaps>
            <rewriteMap name="root">
                <add key="/root/" value="/" />
            </rewriteMap>
        </rewriteMaps>
        <rules>
            <clear />
            <rule name="MyRedirect" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^MYApiTestsite/(api|signalr)(/.*)?" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://mycompany:8080/{R:1}{R:2}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

If you want to use GUI then
[image]