# Route static files to new path in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have 1000 static html page files and html data in Database.
Now i want to move to amazon s3 server, i will move all of my static files to s3.
How i can route the path to the new location, i can't update all of the pages and correct images path.
like:

```
<img src='/myfiles/images/blog/20140606/flow.jpg'/>
```

to

```
Request: /myfiles/images/blog/20140606/flow.jpg
Redirect to: htps://xxx.s3.amazonaws.com/myfiles/images/blog/20140606/flow.jpg
```

i need a route to redirect the request to new location instead of update all files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be using a url rewrite in your web.config like this:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Rewrite to s3" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^/myfiles/images/blog/(.*)" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="s3/mybucketname/{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Found" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
```

Comment: Yes you can, and About the {R:x} {R:x} is used as back reference from the rule pattern (<match url="...">). and you find more about there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16998832/iis-url-rewrite-rn-clarification