# How does a website ignore the URL typo error?

Tags: asp.net, url, url-rewriting

For example, this URL

[`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16998832/iis-url-rewrite-rn-clarification`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16998832/iis-url-rewrite-rn-clarification)

opens the same page as this URL (with typo error)

[`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16998832/iis-url-rewrite-rn-clarificationhhhhhh`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16998832/iis-url-rewrite-rn-clarificationhhhhhh)

(Notice that at the end of the URL I have added "hhhhhh".)

I want to implement the same thing for my application in .NET MVC.

Comment: Yamini, url re-writing and routing are two different concepts. kindly check how to define routes for mvc application.