# Difference between {R:1} and {C:1} on iis web.config file

Tags: php, azure, iis, nginx

ON my job I was asked to migrate a php application running on iis/azure into running via nginx and fpm over a GNU+Linux machine.

Then on the process I encountered a file named `web.config` containing entries for example:

```xml
<action name="SomeName" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url=".*" ignoreCase="true" />
   <conditions>
      <add input="{URL}" pattern="^some_regex^">
   </conditions>
   <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?someaction={C:1}">
</action>
```

Or

```xml
<action name="SomeName" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url=".*" ignoreCase="true" />
   <conditions>
      <add input="{URL}" pattern="^some_regex^">
   </conditions>
   <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?someaction={R:1}">
</action>
```

So far I thought that an nginx mapping like that:

```
^some_regex^ index.php?someaction=$1;
```

Would do the job in both actions (somehow). But I still cannot understand the difference between {C:1} and {R:1} on regex maches I understand that in my nginx would be something like $1 (a subregex match) but what different to the web.config is {C:1} and {R:1} entries?

I am asking because I may need to change the nginx's subregex matches a bit regarding if the match is {C:1} or {R:1}.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

here is your **answer**

Back-references to condition patterns are identified by `{C:N}` where N is from 0 to 9. Back-references to rule patterns are identified by `{R:N}` where N is from 0 to 9. Note that for both types of back-references, `{R:0}` and `{C:0}`, will contain the matched string. For more detailed info you can have a look on: [IIS URL Rewrite {R:N} clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16998832/iis-url-rewrite-rn-clarification)

Further info you can find on: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#using-back-references-in-rewrite-rules

Comment: So in my case what is the rule and what is the case as far as I know on `<conditions></condtions>` section may have more that one conditions does {C:1} has something to do with that? Can you provide an example where the  difference between `{R:N}` and `{C:N}`  is dumb clear?

Comment: that I also have to find.

Comment: I have added another link in an answer which will help you to understand the difference between `{R:N}` and` {C:N}`

Comment: I think the second link is by far more explanatory.