# Routing ASP.Net Core 3.0 Web Application to SubDomain and SubFolder

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes

I need help getting a subdomain to work in my domain. Here's what I've done:

1. Using an FTP program, I created two subfolders in my root folder: WebApp1 and WebApp2
2. From the my web host's Control Panel, I created two Subdomain Pointers: WebApp1.MyDomain.Com pointing to subfolder WebApp1 and WebApp2.MyDomain.Com pointing to subfolder WebApp2
3. Using VS2019Pro I created an ASP.NET Core 3.0 Web Application (not MVC), called WebApp1, and successfully used Web Deploy to upload it to the WebApp1 subfolder.
4. Using a text editor and FTP program I created a simple index.html page and put it in the WebApp2 subfolder.
5. In the root of mydomain.com I made a Web.Config file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
<rules>

<rule name="webapp1.mydomain.com">
<match url=".*" />
<conditions>
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^webapp1.mydomain.com$" />
<add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^/webapp1/" negate="true" />
</conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="\webapp1\{R:0}" />
</rule>

<rule name="webapp2.mydomain.com">
<match url=".*" />
<conditions>
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^webapp2.mydomain.com$" />
<add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^/webapp2/" negate="true" />
</conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="\webapp1\{R:0}" />
</rule>

</rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>​
```

The result:

- Going to **h t t p://WebApp1.mydomain.com, (ASP.Net project) I get a totally blank screen**. No webpage. No error. **However, when I go to h t t p://www.mydomain.com/webapp1 it works totally fine.** I see the ASP.Net Core App that I wrote and it works exactly as I want it to.
- Meanwhile, going to h t t p://WebApp2.mydomain.com, (text editor project) it works flawlessly. So, I know the web.config file is working for a very simple target website, but it's NOT workign when I redirect to the far more complex ASP.Net web application at WebApp1.

What am I doing wrong? **How do I tell my ASP.Net Core 3.0 project in the WebApp1 folder to properly route the incoming requests?**

Thank you for any help and/or suggestions!

Jason

Comment: I haven't done this for a while, but there are a few things I see. 1. Your `webapp2.mydomain.com` rule is actually rewriting to `\webapp1`. 2. I can't remember if the `\\``s in the rewrite actions actually need to be `/`, although it may not matter. 3. I think you should read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16998832/iis-url-rewrite-rn-clarification) as I think `R:0` may not be what you want.

Comment: Thank you, John.  I will check this out!