# IIS Reverse proxy/Global URL Rewrite for "/api/" folder for all sites

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy

I would like to reverse proxy any requests to an IIS instance for any sites where the request is in the '/api/' folder.  I set up a server farm and have the reverse proxy working for everything using the '*' wildcard, but when I want to limit the scope to a RegEx it will not rewrite/proxy to the backend server.  The steps I took at the IIS INSTANCE level:

1. Set up a web farm - only one server in it, machine2
2. Set up a rewrite for '*'
3. Tested against 'http://machine1/site1/api/api1' - it was successfully routed to machine2/site1/api/api1
4. Changed inbound rule from Wildcard to Regular Expressions
5. Changed Pattern to '.*(/.*/api/.*)'  (without the single quotes)
6. Tested against 'http://sarjhennew10vm/site1/api/api1'
7. Request was not routed to machine 2.

Below is a snippet from my applicationHost.config [the root of IIS].

```
    <rewrite>
        <globalRules>
            <rule name="ARR_Farm1_loadbalance" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*(\/.*\/api\/.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://Farm1/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </globalRules>
    </rewrite>
    <proxy enabled="true" />
```

Is it possible to to a global URL re-write to the server farm for any site on the instance for specific folders?

Edit: It was answered below - I am including a picture in case others run into this.  The test pattern isn't clear to me - and counters documentation [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16998832/iis-url-rewrite-rn-clarification).

[image: Test Pattern Matching in IIS]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern is incorrect, you can try below code, and change the rewrite url to https://Farm1/{R: 0}

```
<rule name="ARR_Farm1_loadbalance" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*(\/api\/.*)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="https://Farm1/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Nailed it.  I was looking at the 'test pattern' results, which breaks out by capture groups 0 and 1.  I thought by putting group r:1 (which was just 'site1/api/api1') it would resolve to http://farm1/site1/api/api1, but not the case.  Indeed r:0, which in the test pattern resolved to 'http://machine1/site1/api/api1') resolved to what I wanted.  Not clear to me, but it worked - so thanks!