# What is Rewrite Html tag in web.config

Tags: html, asp.net, web-config

I found this line of code in my web.config, and I cannot understand what does it exactly do for my website. What is the need of this in my web.config?

```
<rule name="RewriteHTML">
          <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">                     
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />                     
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />                 
            </conditions>                 <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.html" />             
</rule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a rule named "RewriteHTML" (that's up to you).

The *match* element is the pattern you want to match (regular expression). In your case, you match everything.

If you want to test Regex: https://regex101.com/

The *action* element tells what should be done with request that match the pattern. The *type* **Rewrite** tells that the request should be rewritten to another URL.

The *conditions* in this case tells to not match requests to files or directories.

So what happens is that you add ".html" to all your incoming requests.

For more clarification on {R:1} notation: [IIS URL Rewrite {R:N} clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16998832/iis-url-rewrite-rn-clarification)

Comment: I think it will omit the  .html from the end of URLs right?

Comment: @nedaDerakhshesh In your case it will add .html to your URLs.